# RecycleView with different width size for each item

Tags: java, android

[I have been using RecycleView with an horizontalScrollView to create this(don't mind the blue ball)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYGT9.png)

What happens is depending on the text size of the tag all the others tags that come after it will have a huge gap between them, below i left an image to show you what is happening.

[third tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V715S.png)

here i have the xml file from recycle view.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/searchNeighborhoodsHorizontalScroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchNeighborhoodsRelative"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/searchNeighborhoodsTagView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is the xml from the recycle item

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/tag_background">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tagText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Text test"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/tagDeleteButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tagText"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tag_close" />
```

Set Adapter

```
 GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), tagList.size(), GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    RecyclerView tagView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.searchNeighborhoodsTagView);
    tagView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    tagView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And Adapter

```
public TagsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setupCard(items, position, context);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView tagText;
    private final ImageButton tagDeleteButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tagText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tagText);
        tagDeleteButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tagDeleteButton);

        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        tagText.setTypeface(LarSingleton.exoMedium);
    }

    public void setupCard(ArrayList<String> items, int position, Context context) {
        tagText.setText(items.get(position).toString());
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this problem? or why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new
            GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

> Suggestion you can achieve it without using horizontal scroll view as recyclerview has its own scroll

Comment: i have tried removing all the margins but the same happens i always have a gap between the elements because of the text size of the elements. And i can't remove the horizontal scroll because if i do.. for some reason everything collapses

Comment: dude you are a genius i love you =**